# How to use BootStrap inside a WordPress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in WordPress and BootStrap CSS framework and I have the following doubt:

I have installed this theme that integrate BootStrap framework and I want to use it as a start point: http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/

I have change the background color of the homepage changing the **background-color** property into the body field in a file named **bootstrapwp.css** inside my theme using **FireBug** plugin

Ok...my doubts are:

1) Why this CSS file is named **bootstrapwp.css** and not **bootstrap.css** as in the downloaded BootStrap 3 framework? And why this file is slightly different form the dowloaded **bootstrap.css** file?

2) What is the better way to change a style in BootStra? I can change it directly inside my **bootstrapwp.css** or is better do it in another file overriding this behavior?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 3):

Andrea:

There are a lot of answers for your questions but I will work to simplify it for you.

First, what the developers are trying to do is get Bootstrap functionality within the Wordpress CMS. They are two entirely different animals. Bootstrap consists of individual pages that must be hand coded. Wordpress is a Content Management System (CMS) where you can apply a style, theme, sidebar, template or widget and have it appear on every page site-wide.

So, what the developer is doing is using the bootstrapwp.css file to handle the CSS for the entire Bootstrap themed Wordpress site. Remember, this is NOT a Bootstrap site. It is a Bootstrap themed Wordpress site that seeks to incorporate the functionality and design of Bootstrap within the confines of the Wordpress Codex.

If you're running a Wordpress site, the best way to change a style is always going to be in the CSS file provided by the child theme.

Comment: Ok, so let's see if I understand what you mean: I know that BootStrap is a collection of components with related CSS settings (for example menu components). I understand that I can simply apply a BootStrap menu component (as a Navbar) in a simple HTML page but that this could be pretty complicated in WordPress because in a CMS the menu have a specific logic (this is only to do an example, corect me if I am wrong). So come back to my previous post: do you mean that the developer of the theme have take and integrate some BootStrap behavior (some components and related CSS) in the WP theme?

Comment: and also: what do you exactly mean when you say me that: "the best way to change a style is always going to be in the CSS file provided by the child theme"?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can try Impulse Press. It's the most complete Wordpress Bootstrap 3 starter Theme
Take a look at the demo [impulsepress.twoimpulse.com](http://impulsepress.twoimpulse.com)
with this you can change your css style in bootstrap-theme.css and don't touch bootstrap.css , so when we have an update it doesn't ruin your site styles

And Vincent Polisi is right, you can also make a child theme and get Impulse Press always updated